# Why "django-admin.py startproject myproject" doesn't create a project but instead open django-admin.py in Eclipse?

Tags: python, django, eclipse

I've installed `Python 3.4` & `Django v1.7` in my computer `win8`. Everything works well so far.
Then I installed `Eclipse` & `PyDev`. Everything seems ok until, I try to create a new project with theses lines :

```
django-admin.py startproject myproject
```

Results : myproject was not created, & instead the django-admin.py files is opened in Eclipse.

How can I fixed this issue ?

Comment: FWIW, I would highly recommend ditching Eclipse and PyDev in favor of Sublime Text + Anaconda or PyCharm.

Comment: Thx Brandon, why is it better to use Sublime Text & Anaconda rather than PyDev ?

Comment: I find PyDev to be so... much... slower... than almost any other Python code assistance out there. I use Sublime Text on Windows 8.1 on a Lenovo P400 Ideapad and it launches nearly instantaneously. Plus, it is, hands down, the most flexible code editor I have used since 1997.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found.
I have changed the behavior of my python files & associated them to Eclipse. Eventually, I re-associate them with IDLE/Python. And everything work well now.